# How to avoid namespace and source file name confliction in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a class let's say it's called "Apples". Let's say that class is in a .cs file in a folder called "Apples"

```
Project
   -Apples
       -Apples.cs
   -main.cs
```

How can i reference it without writing this:

Main.cs

```
Apples.Apples.testVar = 2;
```

and just write

Main.cs:

```
Apples.testVar = 2;
```

Is there a way to do this, or will i have to put up with it or change the folder name?

Comment: *Do not name a class the same as it's namespace.* http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Comment: Its the namespace, not the folder name, that you have to be concerned with.  (although these will be the same by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this at the top of your file -

`using Apples = Apples.Apples;`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a folder in visual studio and create a class in it, Visual Studio (and possibly other IDEs) will automatically append the folder's name to the namespace of any file created from that folder.

That DOES NOT mean in any way that the namespace has to stay that way. The "folder" is purely for organizational purposes and plays no part in the compilation of your code. The filename doesn't matter to the actual code either.  If you look in your Apples.cs just change:

```
namespace Apples.Apples
{
     //....
```

to

```
namespace Apples
{
    //...
```

It's simply the rule that your IDE is using as an assumption to what you want.  You're not required to follow it.

EDIT: At least that's what I assume to be the misunderstanding here as you're focusing on the folder name - which means nothing to the code and only matters to you. Additionally as previously mentioned you might be hung up on ambiguity between namespace name and class name. As mentioned in other answers it's a bad idea to name a class the same as it's namespace.

By default the global namespace for your project will be the same name as your project. So if you named your project "Apples" and then made a folder called "Apples" and created a class within that folder called "Apples" - You'd then navigate to your class by following the chain of namespaces:

```
Apples.Apples.Apples
```

You're drawing the conclusion that you have to do this based on the folder/file names but it's really the namespaces/classes. You have several options here but the bottom line is in order to remove confusion and mess 2 or all 3 of those "Apples" need to change. Changing the file name or folder name will not work. you have to change the class name and at least one of the namespace names. Something more appropriate:

```
AppleProject.Apples.AppleBase
```

or even as simple as:

```
Apples.Apple // removed the extra namespace in the middle
```

Answer (score 1):

You could alias "Apples" in your using statements:

```
using Apples = Apples.Apples.testVar;
```

Or whatever you'd like to make it easier to read.

Comment: Yes, but it still takes the word Apples as a reference to the namespace not the class

Comment: For this to work, the alias needs to be anything other than "Apples" :) Otherwise, the compiler will still not know whether you mean a namespace or the class.

Comment: What I think is not entirely clear is what exactly `testVar` is in this context.  Is it a nested class of the `Apples` class or a variable name?

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you are using C# you just add it in the using references up top of your code file you are on:

EG:

using Apples.Apples;

You just need to ensure you have the reference to the project set if it is not in your current project.